# how to deserialize php string in iOS

Tags: php, nsstring, deserialization

Here is a string sample that I get from my DB which is maintained in php. I am not sure as how to use it in my iPhone as to extract various values:

```
a:27:{s:26:"the-muse_disable_post_meta";s:5:"false";s:31:"the- muse_disable_published_date";s:4:"true";s:23:"the-muse_disable_author";s:5:"false";s:24:"the-muse_disable_coments";s:5:"false";s:19:"the-muse_page_title";s:13:"default_title";s:21:"the-muse_custom_title";s:0:"";
```

Comment: Can you solve it. i have same problem as you

Answer (score 0):

Change the response to a JSON Array and you can simply parse it in every coding language.

PHP

```
    echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: How to change this string in JSON using objective -C is the actual problem  ? thanks